# Python - nesting if else inside return

Tags: python

Can an if-else expression be the argument of 'return'?

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
return m +
    if a:
        x
    elif b:
        y
    else c:
        z
```

I could write as:

```
addend = m
if a:
        m += x
    elif b:
        m += y
    else c:
        m += z
return m
```

Comment: Have you tried writing a function using the return form you are asking about? Please share that function. When you ran that code what result did you get? If you don't understand the outcome please share it with us.

Comment: def rental_car_costs(days):
        return days*40 +
            if days>=7:
                (-50)
            elif days>=3:
                (-20)

gives me: syntax error: invalid syntax

Comment: So the system did tell you that you could not do what you were doing. It told you that it was a syntax error. If you didn't understand the syntax error then posting the code and asking for help resolving that syntax error and/or asking for a better option would be a better way to ask your question. Not trying to be nasty, just trying to help you get the best out of SO. Check the answer from paxdiablo for some better ways to do what you are trying to do and to resolve other problems in your code.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback on how I formulated the question. 

Is there room on SO for general questions on how to combine elements in python? I know in LISP, you could certainly plug the output of a conditional into the equivalent of 'return'. My question here is meant to be: can the same be done with python?

Comment: Actually, if I'm being honest, I find your comment condescending and disingenuous. The question I asked *is* what I want to find out - there's no other, hidden, implicit issue behind the question that I'm trying to make you guess. I was not looking for a better option, for example. I really did want to know how if-else could be combined with return.

I'm optimistic that your response is not typical of this community.

Comment: I am sorry you feel that way but I am just trying to help you get the best out of SO. Showing that you have run the code you are presenting helps in getting help with code questions. The rest of your response about a 'hidden, implicit issue' is a mystery to me since I never thought nor suggested any such thing. I was only suggesting how to phrase your question in a way most likely to get the best answer. See paxdiablo's edit for proof. All the rest is in your head and not in mine. I hope that providing polite, well intended, advice on how best to use SO is, in fact, typical of this community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can use Python's ternary method, such as:

```
return m + (x if a else y if b else z)
```

But it *may* be more readable to just do something like:

```
if a: return m + x
if b: return m + y
return       m + z
```

> As an aside, `else c:` is not really sensible code: you use `if/elif` if you *have* a condition, or `else` for *default* action (no condition).

---

For example, in terms of the code you posted in a comment, you could opt for the succinct, yet still self-documenting:

```
def rental_car_costs(days):
    basecost = days * 40
    discount = 50 if days >= 7 else 20 if days >= 3 else 0
    return basecost - discount
```